# Typescript and React (with Gatsby loader): unable to import images as modules

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gatsby

First, I don't think Gatsby is involved in problem as runnning `tsc -p .` will detect the same compilation errors, before gatby's `yarn start` is ran.

I have a folder with some react tsx files I want to compile

```
src/
  @types/
    index.d.ts
  components/
    bottom/bottom.tsx
    layout.tsx
  images/
    email.png
    costs.png 
gatsby-config.js
gatsby-node.js
tsconfig.json
package.json
```

I want `bottom.tsx` to load email.png, but I have this error

[image: TS2307: cannot load image module]

[As written in this post](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter/issues/12), I declare all pictures as modules in `src/@types/index.d.ts`. I have created a interface in this file for test urpose, and the file is correctly read by the compiler.

```
declare module '*.jpg';
declare module '*.png';​

export interface Thing {
    name: string
}
```

Using import as or adding content to module declaration won't change anything. However the code is running fine if I ignore typescript compilator :

```
//@ts-ignore
import email from '../../images/email.png'
//@ts-ignore
import logo from '../../images/logo-bw.png'
```

It works, so the structure of the code is ok with Gatsby, but obviously I lose a lot of benefits of using typescript as images is a big part of a website... Plus, there is no IDE autocompletion to help image import.

This Gatsby starter is made to be open source, so you can check the configuration at this branch : https://github.com/robusta-code/gatsby-the-robust/tree/0.0.1

Note that loading css or sass modules would be ok : `import '../styles/home.scss'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow... The problem is that my `index.d.ts` was exporting an interface !

> In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a
>   top-level import or export is considered a module. Conversely, a file
>   without any top-level import or export declarations **is treated as a
>   script whose contents are available in the global scope** (and therefore
>   to modules as well)

Removing `export interface Thing{}` was enough.

Comment: The only problem is that my IDE IntelliJ is not proposing autocomplete for image file name